# How to export SassDoc data as Json instead of HTML

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

I'm currently using the following gulp function that uses `SassDoc^2.7.3` to automatically document all of my Scss code.

```js
const sassdoc = require('sassdoc')

//...

function documentScss() {
  var options = {
    dest: './public/sassdoc',
    verbose: true,
  }

  return src('./src/scss/**/*.scss').pipe(sassdoc(options))
}
```

Inside the directory `./public/sassdoc`, an `index.html` file and an `assets` folder are created as it is Sassdoc's default behavior. I was looking for a configuration option, theme or library that would instead create a `.json` file with the same content. I just want to be able to use my Sassdoc documentation in other js modules, and I think that generating the documentation in a `.json` file during the build would be best.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a gulp function, I was able to do it using the sassdoc cli. The command `sassdoc src/ --parse` Will output all comments inside the src folder to the terminal. With a slight modification, you can turn that output into a `.json` file:

`sassdoc src/ --parse > ./sassdoc.json`